# PHP leave CSV column blank if user input[checkbox] and textarea are left empty

Tags: php, csv

I am submitting the values of my inputs into a CSV file and trying to make them if the user leaves an input empty the csv will leave a blank column as well. I have succeeded to do the following with an input[type=text] but for some reason textarea and checkbox which are left empty won't skip the column in the CSV.

```
$data = $_POST;
$data['Nachname'] = array_key_exists('Nachname', $_POST) ? $_POST['Nachname'] : ""; // this is a standard input[type=text]
$data['same-purchaser'] = array_key_exists('same-purchaser', $_POST) ? $_POST['same-purchaser'] : ""; // this is a checkbox 
$data['Interessiert'] = array_key_exists('Interessiert', $_POST) ? $_POST['Interessiert'] : ""; // this is a textarea

$handle = fopen((__dir__)."/submissions.csv", "a+");
fputcsv($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);

// this is my html for the checkbox
<div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0; text-align: left;">
    <label class="wrapper">Random text
    <input value="1" type="checkbox" name="same-purchaser" id="same-purchaser">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</div>

// this is the textbox
<div class="form-row">
    <textarea name="" id="Interessiert" rows="8" name="Interessiert" placeholder="Besucher interessiert sich für"></textarea>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried using isset instead of array_key_exists by no success so far.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "skip the column?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When submitting `<input type="text">` and `<textarea>`, they will always be posted even if they are empty. `<input type="checkbox">` is only going to show up in post data if it is checked.

I'm a bit confused about what you mean by "skip the column," so I've included two options - one of which should be what you are looking for.

The following will "skip the column" in that it will only render columns in the CSV that contain data (I don't think this is what you want):

```
$data = [];
$fields = ['Nachname', 'same-purchaser', 'Interessiert'];
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
        $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
        if ($value !== '') {
            $data[] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want the column to be rendered as the empty string if the user doesn't supply it:

```
$data = [];
$fields = ['Nachname', 'same-purchaser', 'Interessiert'];
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
        $data[] = trim($_POST[$field]);
    } else {
        $data[] = '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has worked perfectly exactly as I want. Now when I don't click on the checkbox it leaves a blank column in my CSV which is great. However it's not pushing the <textarea> value into the CSV. I have used  your second example

Comment: In your example code for your `<textarea>` you have two `name` attributes. One is empty, the other is set to `Interessiert`. Try removing the `name=""` from it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks mate, I must be blind!